# Magento : send file attachements in Emails

Tags: magento-1, email, magento-community

in a custom module, I use this function to send Emails:

```
public function sendMail($errorCod, $errorMsg) {

    $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');

    $recipients = array(
            Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom1/name') => Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom1/email'),  
            Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom2/name') => Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom2/email')
    );

    foreach ($recipients as $recipient):
        $mail->setToEmail($recipient);

        $mailBody  = "<b>Error Code: </b>".$errorCod."<br />";
        $mailBody .= "<b>Error Massage: </b>".$errorMsg."<br />";

        $mail->setBody($mailBody);
        $mail->setSubject('Lorem Ipsum');
        $mail->setFromEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email'));
        $mail->setFromName("Lorem Ipsum");
        $mail->setType('html');

        try {
            $mail->send();
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
    }

    endforeach;

}
```

I try to send 2 attachements files in the same E-mail.

How can I do that, without using the Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template Model.

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to use Zend_Mail. See:

```
public function sendMail($errorCod = "", $errorMsg = "")
{

    $mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');

    $recipients = array(
        Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom1/name') => Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom1/email'),
        Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom2/name') => Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom2/email'),
    );
    $mailBody   = "<b>Error Code: </b>" . $errorCod . "<br />";
    $mailBody .= "<b>Error Massage: </b>" . $errorMsg . "<br />";
    $mail->setBodyHtml($mailBody)
        ->setSubject('Lorem Ipsum')
        ->addTo($recipients)
        ->setFrom(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email'), "FromName");

    //file content is attached
    $file       = Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'log' . DS . 'exception.log';
    $attachment = file_get_contents($file);
    $mail->createAttachment(
        $attachment,
        Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
        Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
        'attachment_1.log'
    );
    $file       = Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'log' . DS . 'system.log';
    $attachment = file_get_contents($file);
    $mail->createAttachment(
        $attachment,
        Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
        Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
        'attachment_2.log'
    );

    try {
        $mail->send();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly, I also implemented this functionallity with Zend_Mail some time ago.

Comment: The only issue I have with this is if you're on a shared hosting server, regardless of if you set a sender, it is not the permitted sender of the server itself (if you look at the email headers for `Received-SPF:`

Comment: Magento already handles sending emails with attachments, I don't find it relevant to bypass its functions

Answer (score 6):

Just to get another answer here you can also rewrite `Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php` and create an `addAttachment` function. This example will add a pdf but you can extend this to make it work with any file type.

```
public function addAttachment(Zend_Pdf $pdf){
    $file = $pdf->render();
    $attachment = $this->getMail()->createAttachment($file);
    $attachment->type = 'application/pdf';
    $attachment->filename = 'yourfile.pdf';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Copy this code in any phtml or controller to send mail with attachment file:

```
  $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
  $mailTemplate->setSenderName('Sender Name'); 
  $mailTemplate->setSenderEmail('sender@sender.email');
  $mailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Subject Title');
  $mailTemplate->setTemplateText('Body Text');
  // add attachment
  $mailTemplate->getMail()->createAttachment(
          file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('base') . '/media/file/file.pdf'), //location of file
          Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
          Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
          Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
          'file.pdf'
  );
  $mailTemplate->send('toemail@email.com','subject','set message');
```

Comment: thanks it is working. But what is the use of 'subject' and 'set message' in the last line because as I can see the subject is already set line 4 and message is set on line 5?

Comment: thanks @prince your code used for me in observer :)

Comment: Yes, no need to use Zend_Mail directly

Answer (score 2):

//1 I used a request quote folder as requestquote in media directory for saving // uploaded images

//2 There is an array of custom variables to be passed to transactional email //email template was created in magento admin and its template id 3

//Code has been tested on Magento 1.9.1.0

//Code starts just below

```
$uploadfilename = '';

if( !empty($_FILES["rfloorplanattachment"]["name"])  )
{

    $image_ext = end(explode('.',$_FILES["rfloorplanattachment"]["name"]));
    $allowed_ext =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg','jpeg','pdf','doc','docx','rtf','odt');

    $uploadfilename = md5(substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, rand(1,100).rand(1,100))).str_replace(" ","_",$_FILES["rfloorplanattachment"]["name"]); 
    $source_upl         = $_FILES["rfloorplanattachment"]["tmp_name"];
    $target_path_upl = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename;  
    if(in_array($image_ext ,$allowed_ext ) ) {
        @move_uploaded_file($source_upl, $target_path_upl);
    }
}


$senderName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');
$senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');

$templateId = 3;
$sender = Array('name' => $senderName,'email' => $senderEmail);


$requestquotesvars = array(
            'firmname'     =>  $customer->getFirstname()
        );


$emaiName = 'Request Quote Firms';

$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

$translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
$transactionalEmail = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
if(file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename) )
{
$transactionalEmail->getMail()
                ->createAttachment(
        file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename),
        Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
        Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
        basename($uploadfilename)
    );
}
$transactionalEmail->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $companymail, $emailName, $requestquotesvars, $storeId);
$translate->setTranslateInline(true);

   unlink(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename);
```

Answer (score 2):

Enjoy: Working example

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setType(Zend_Mime::MULTIPART_RELATED);
$mail->setBodyHtml($html_body);
$mail->setFrom('support@example.com', 'Example');
$mail->addTo('your_email@gmail.com', 'Arslan');
$mail->setSubject('Sending email using Zend Framework');
$dir = Mage::getBaseDir();
$path = "test.html";  // any file named test.html at root
$file = $mail->createAttachment(file_get_contents($path));
$file ->type        = 'text/csv';
$file ->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE;
$file ->encoding    = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
$file ->filename    = 'test.html';
try {
    //Confimation E-Mail Send
    $mail->send();
}
catch(Exception $error) {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($error->getMessage());
    return false;
}
```