# Attaching multiple PDF to an email

Tags: email-templates, attachment

Im trying to send the sales order email with three attached PDF files.
At first i need to attach the terms/conditions for b2b and b2c but the cancellation policy also.

I searched a while and just found the "FOOMAN EMAIL ATTACHMENTS" where i cant attach more than just one file.

Maybe someone got a similar problem and could tell me how to realize this?

Comment: See http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9652/magento-send-file-attachements-in-emails

Answer (score 2):

If you are already using our Email Attachments extension you can make use of the event it emits to add additional attachments (this is how the extension itself does it). For the order confirmation email you would listen for the event `fooman_emailattachments_before_send_order` and then in your event observer class you can use something like this:

```
public function beforeSendOrder($observer)
{
    $filePath = 'full/path/to/file.pdf';
    $mailTemplate = $observer->getEvent()->getTemplate();
    $mailTemplate->getMail()->createAttachment(
        file_get_contents($filePath),
        'application/pdf',
        Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
        basename($filePath)
    );
}
```

Comment: Hey, i'm using Magento 2 fooman email attachments. How i use this observer event to attach multiple pdf.

Comment: It's the same event name, and then take a look \Fooman\EmailAttachments\Observer\AbstractObserver.

Comment: Hi, thanks i found it. and working perfectly.