# How to send mail by getting the details from database?

Tags: magento-1.8, database, send-mail

I had created a dropdown list with fields lab,pharmacy and food.When

1.I select the lab it has to send the mail for those islab checkbox is true.

2.when I select the pharmacy it has to send the mail for those ispharmacy checkbox is true and in the same way for food.

I have tried for islab but I could not add for rest of them.
Please help me.

mail.phtml

```
   <?php
   $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
   $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');  
     $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.islab=?', '1' 
 );
       $alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
     foreach($alldata as $data)
     {
          sendMailserviceAction($data['email'],$data['name']);
     }

     function sendMailserviceAction($email,$pname){
 //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);
 $cemail=$_POST['email'];
 $bloodgroup=$_POST['bloodgroup'];
 $unitsrequired=$_POST['unitsrequired'];
 $requireddate=$_POST['requiredby'];
 $rcity=$_POST['rcity'];
 $city=$_POST['city'];
 $hospital=$_POST['hospital'];
 //$location=$_POST['location'];

 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
 $yourbloodgroup=$_POST['yourbloodgroup'];

 $html=
'Hi,
<p>
<p><h2>Requisition Details:</h2> </p>
<p>Bloodgroup: '.$bloodgroup.'</p>
 <p>Units Required:'.$unitsrequired.'</p>
 <p>Required By:'. $requireddate.'</p>
 <p>City: '.$rcity.'</p>
 <p>Hospital:'.$hospital.'</p>

 <p><h2>Seeker Details:</h2></p>

 <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
 <p>Email : '.$cemail.'</p>
 <p>Mobile Number: '.$mobile.'</p>
 <p>City: '.$city.'</p>
 <p>YourBloodgroup:'.$yourbloodgroup.'</p>'

;

 $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
  $mail->setToName($pname);
 $mail->setToEmail($email);
 $mail->setBody($html);
 $mail->setSubject('Blood Donor');
 $mail->setFromEmail('admin@labwise.in');
 $mail->setFromName("Labwise");
//$mail->addBcc("admin@labwise.in");
$mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

   try {
  $mail->send();
  //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your Order is successfully Completed');
  //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
//return '<h2>Your Order has been submitted. Thank you for using labwise.   </h2>';
  //$this->_redirect('');
  }
 catch (Exception $e) {
  //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
   //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
 // return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>'; 
 //$this->_redirect('');
 }
 }
 echo sendMailserviceAction();

 ?>
```

Comment: this is database column name islab?

Comment: yes islab is column name in mg_serviceprovider table

Comment: what are value for islab in database?

Comment: islab is checkbox

Comment: checkbox have value what are the value of it check the database?

Comment: How to check the value.Can you please suggest me

Comment: go to database and check the table mg_serviceprovider  and see column value

Comment: if checkbox is true it is 1 if not it is 0

Comment: did this code fetching the record?

Comment: yes  but i want for ispharmacy also.It is should sent the mail for islab and ispharmacy providers.

Comment: they are in same table or other table?

Comment: they are in the same table

Comment: they are both have value true and false and also you want to combine query or seperate?

Comment: the providers may have both islab and ispharmacy values are true neither they have any one of them is true.it has to send mail based on the true values

Comment: Ex:ravi is provider he has is lab=1 ispharmacy=0 || mouni is another provider she has islab=1 ispaharmacy=1.For both of the providers the mail has to sent for which the checkbox value is 1

Comment: added the answer kindly check n feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this query for or condition..

```
 $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
       $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');  
       $query="SELECT *
      FROM mg_serviceprovider  where islab='1' or ispharmacy='1'";
  $alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($query);

         foreach($alldata as $data)
         {
              sendMailserviceAction($data['email'],$data['name']);
         }
```

Comment: if islab=1 and ispharmacy=0 it has to send the email for islab provider.Does it works for this condition also.

Comment: yes is it using the or condition 1 condition is true it will work

Comment: Ok.When I select the pharmacy from dropdown list it shows an another field upload button and I need to send the attached file to these providers also.How can I send these attachement

Comment: ask another question for that with the form that have file name of file. i will answer briefly.

Comment: this code is working or not? and for attachment this will answer ur requirement http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9652/magento-send-file-attachements-in-emails

Comment: working I have posted my new question.Please review it and suggest me please