# How to send product images through mail

Tags: magento-1.9, email, product-images

I want to send all `images` of a product from `product detail` page by mail after assiging `email id` to mail form like below link

https://superwholesalebazaar.biz/shop/sarees-catalogs/bundle-of-15-cotton-sarees/

I am using `magento 1.9.2`.

Comment: in send mail form pass your product is as well and from that product id get all images and send mail as attachments

Comment: Can you send me code structure with mail form

Comment: to get all product image check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151410/how-to-display-all-product-images-on-magento#answer-22152083)

Comment: To send mail with attachment check [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9652/magento-send-file-attachements-in-emails#answer-9662)