# How to set mail type to "pdf attachment" in sendmail controller?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to send a pdf attachment by email. But the email content only show text "Object". My TCPDF Plugin is working, but why my script can't send email with an attachment?

Here's my script :

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');
$mail->setType(Zend_Mime::MULTIPART_RELATED);
$mail->setBodyHtml($html);
$mail->setFrom('penawaran@mail.id', 'Nekindo');
$mail->addTo('mail@mail.com', 'Syahidah Humairoh');
$mail->setSubject('subject');
    try {
        $mail->send();
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your request has been sent');
        $this->_redirect('offer');
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
        $this->_redirect('offer');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you have create attachment. First you have to put pdf in directory

```
$pdfName="Penawaran";
$pdf->Output(Mage::getBaseDir().'/media/tmp/'.$pdfName.'.pdf', 'F');
$pdfurl=Mage::getBaseDir().'/media/tmp/'.$pdfName.'.pdf';
     $mail->createAttachment(
                    file_get_contents($pdfurl),
                    'application/pdf',
                    Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                    Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                    $pdfName.'.pdf' 
                );
```

Comment: why the result is error page 
? it says "Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons."

Comment: check the `var/log` folder for error and share the error

Comment: in my error number report says Invalid method Mage_Core_Model_Email::createAttachment(Array
(...........

Comment: @syahidahhumairoh check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9652/magento-send-file-attachements-in-emails

Comment: @syahidahhumairoh  replace `$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');` with `$mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');` and try that

Comment: Thankyou Qaisar

Comment: @QaisarSatti Method createAttachment() uses 5 parameters only. You have declared 2 mime types. 'application/pdf' and 'application/octet-stream'. I think you will get error with that code.

Comment: @puntable i did not get any error but thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

You are just putting the PDF object as the text body of the email.  So when the `__toString` method is called on the object it is just returning "Object".  Instead you want to load the PDF file in to a Zend_Pdf object, render it and use that output as the attachment.

```
        $mail->createAttachment(
            Zend_Pdf::load($pdfFilePath)->render(),
            'application/pdf',
            Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
            Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                      'My_Custom_Filename.pdf'
        );
```

Comment: the result is error page "Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons."

Comment: So what is in the `var/log/error.log` or `var/report/*` file?   There should be a report number on the error page which links to a filename in the `var/report` folder.