# How to send attachments in magento 1.9 mail?

Tags: magento-1.9

```
                $name           = $post["name"];
                $email          = $post["email"];
                $address_line_1 = $post["address"]; 
                $attachment     = $post["attachment"]; 
                $body           = "";

                $to      = "abc@gmail.com";
                $subject = "Career Inquiry";
                $body   .= "<p>New Career Inquiry.</p>";
                $body   .= "<p>Name : " . $name . "<p>";
                $body   .= "<p>Email  : " . $email . "<p>";
                $body   .= "<p>Address Line 1 : " . $address_line_1 . "<p>";
                //$body   .= "<p>Address Line 2 : " . $address_line_2 .   "<p>";
                //$body   .= "<p>Address Line 3 : " . $address_line_3 . "<p>";
                //$body   .= "<p>City : " . $city . "<p>";
                //$body   .= "<p>Post Code : " . $postcode . "<p>";
                //$body   .= "<p>Country : " . $country . "<p>";

                $body .= "<p>Kind regards,</p><p>example Admin</p>";

                $from = $email;

                $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
                $mail->setToName('Pranav');
                $mail->setToEmail($to);
                $mail->setBody($body);
                $mail->setSubject($subject);
                $mail->setFromEmail($from);
                $mail->setFromName($name); //Set from name
                $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format
                //$mail->setBodyHTML($body);  // your content or message

                //add attachment start                
                $base_path = Mage::getBaseDir('base');
                $uploadfile = $base_path."\media\\resume\\" . basename($_FILES['attachment']['name']);
                $filename =$_FILES['attachment']['name'];
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
                $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
                //add attachment end                

                $mail->send();

                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your inquiry     was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for     contacting us.');
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
```

Comment: You can refer to this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/9662/72475 This is using Zend mail

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in phtml or controller to send mail with attached file

```
$mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
$mailTemplate->setSenderName('Sender Name'); 
$mailTemplate->setSenderEmail('sender@sender.email');
$mailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Subject Title');
$mailTemplate->setTemplateText('Body Text');
// add attachment
$mailTemplate->getMail()->createAttachment(
        file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('base') . '/media/file/file.pdf'), //location of file
        Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
        Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
        'file.pdf'
);
$mailTemplate->send('toemail@email.com','subject','set message');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add Attachment :-**

```
$mailTemplate->getMail()->createAttachment(
          file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('base') . '/media/file/file.pdf'), //location of file
          Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
          Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
          Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
          'file.pdf'
  );
  $mailTemplate->send('toemail@email.com','subject','set message');
```